# Similar to Axis X, Y - multiple values which needs to be checked, how to do it?

Tags: php, algorithm, function, math

I got many tables which need to be checked for specific values

I will need to input specific numbers and then I need a function to check if the square block is found in the particular region, if so, what number that region got (70 or 75).

Values are:

0.00 till -12.00 (left vertical metter)
0.00 till +4.00 (upper horizontal metter)

Numbers 75 or 70 are just numbers wich are set for the whole block.

Each blue square block is 0.25 in both metters.

For example, if I input -11.00 and +2.00 square found with number 70, another example, when I put -5.00 and 2.25 square found with 75, when input -11.00 and +1.00 no go.

Anyone got idea how to do it ?

[table http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/9449/imag0965.jpg](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/9449/imag0965.jpg)

I started to write function but i ended to a point where i just don't know how to do it.

Comment: No no, graphs are in my cataloque, I will take single graphs and write theem in to values to database. Still i need to have idea how to make function, bcoz i don't know what values need to be taken from that graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea.  From the picture it looks like the functions are liner in the region you specified so you can use y = mx + b to get the equation for each line (I see at least 4).  This page http://www.purplemath.com/modules/slopgrph.htm explains how to compute the line equations you need.

Once you have the formulas for the lines, given an point(X,Y) you can use the X value of your point to compute the y values for each of your lines, and then compare your point's Y against each of your y's in order:

```
if (Point_Y < y_first){ 
  // in region 1
} else if(Point_Y >= y_first && Point_Y < y_second){
  // region 2
} else if(Point_Y >= y_second && Point_Y < y_third){
  // in region 3
} .... etc
```

You should probably also check that the point is in the range given by the graph you have as you don't know for certain what the graph looks like out of the range.  This is easier to do:

```
if(Point_Y <= y_max && Point_Y >= y_min 
    && Point_X <= x_max && Point_X >= x_min){
    // in range
}
```

Comment: you also have to round the line and point values properly to fit the points to the grid.

Comment: That's right. If the regions have to exactly match the grid you must set 'one unit' to the length and with of each cell in the units given in your picture.

Comment: Thx guys, i will have to think now :)